# Tethering a TO-92 IC to a PCB

Tags: pcb, cables, pcb-assembly, socket

I need to tether a TO-92 package IC to a PCB - as shown in figure below. The cable length would be less than 50mm.
[image: Conceptual figure]

Questions:

1. How can I achieve CONN1 - i.e, attaching a cable (comprising of at
   least 3 wires, for the 3 pins of the TO-92 IC) to the PCB.
2. How can I achieve CONN2 - i.e., attaching the cable to the TO-92 IC when the IC is not on any firm surface.

Comment: I usually use solder and heatshrink.

Comment: I would find it tricky to solder the 3 wires directly to the TO-92 IC pins (for CONN2). Would you use any particular kind of wire in such a situation?

Comment: Nothing larger than AWG24 if I can help it.

Comment: Is this for a DS1820? You can buy them with a metal cap and wires attached, neatly crimped an all. Add a CONN1 to your taste and your are done?

Comment: Similar [post](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/84281/what-is-a-good-way-to-solder-small-transistor-to-wire), check it.

Answer (score 3):

Use a 3-pin header cable:

[image: picture]

with the header plug on both sides. The TO-92 will plug neatly into that. I´m not sure exactly how you can then fix it all off-board, but that shouldn´t be too difficult.